# jquery accessing form element after ajax reply

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sending form to server and when I receive it back I need to access its elements

Here goes code.

some html

```
<here is the form>
<div style='border-style:solid' id='user_pic_n_1'></div>
```

and javascript

```
pic_type=($(this).attr('pic_type'));                    
pic_number=($(this).attr('pic_number'));
```

explanation : pic_type gets > `user_pic` and pic_number gets > `1`

so the form is `user_pic_form_n_1`

```
$('#'+pic_type+'_form_n_'+pic_number).ajaxSubmit({
    success: function(responseimage)
    {
$('#'+pic_type+'_n_'+pic_number).html(responseimage);
```

now when the form gets into div, I need to get it's inputs values.

please write code sample of how can I Access it

In my example i'm trying to get values by alert like this but probably I write with mistakes

```
alert($(\"#'+pic_type+'_form_n_'+pic_number+' input[name=error]\").val());
```

elements name is 'error' so I'm trying to get it from the form.

**UPDATE**

Here is HTML form which I get from AJAX

```
<form id='user_pic_form_n_1' name='user_pic_form_n_1'   action='/serv/pic_processor.php' method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' name='error' value='456'/>
</form>
```

So when it gets from server into responseimage variable, I put that into Div and then I want to access this form and alert value of tag named 'error'

Comment: What is this? `$(this).attr('pic_type')`

Comment: Is this really how your code looks?

Comment: This is really badly worded, but I think what you're saying is that you want to search your AJAX response data, which is HTML, for a form and get a value from one of the form fields?

Comment: @Ally you are correct, I'm trying but getting errors

Comment: @VIDesignz it's part of the code which is enough to understand what I want.

Comment: Im saying, since when is `pic_type` an attribute?

Comment: post some sample html from reponse, unless you are nesting a form inside a form code should work

Comment: @VIDesignz  prior to `data-` attributes was common practice to use arbitrary attributes. Won't pass w3c validator but you can read them with `attr()`

Comment: @charlietfl I can respect that...thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the element contain the response html as a context along with selector.

```
selectorElem = '#'+pic_type+'_n_'+pic_number;
$(selectorElem).html(responseimage);
$('form[name=A] #B', $(selectorElem))
```

Edit, based on comments

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/bzMHu/)**

*Html*

```
<form id='user_pic_form_n_1' name='user_pic_form_n_1'   action='/serv/pic_processor.php' method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' name='error' value='456'/>
</form>​
```

*Javascript*

```
pic_type = 'user_pic';
pic_number= '1';
selectorElem = pic_type+'_form_n_'+pic_number;
selectorElem = 'form[name='+selectorElem +'] :hidden[name=error]';
alert($(selectorElem).val());
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused maybe we try without A, B ?  Form name will be the same to pic_type+'_form_n_'+pic_number. input tag which I want has name 'error'. So I get in responseimage the whole HTML with that form, then I put it into DIV, so now it's on the page. ANd after it I want to access this form and alert value of 'error' tag. Please write the code

Comment: It would be lot more easier for us if you post the html from which you want to extract the element and indicate the element you need from that html.

Comment: Try this and tell me if it works, alert($('form[name=A] :hidden[name=error]', $(selectorElem)).val()); or alert($(selectorElem).find('#user_pic_form_n_1 name=error').val())

Comment: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #user_pic_form_n_1 name=error

Comment: but now there is last problem,  alert($('form[name=A] :hidden[name=error]', $(selectorElem)).val());  works but instead of A I want to put there pic_type+'_form_n_'+pic_number  But when I do it I get Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: form[name=pic_type+'_form_n_'+pic_number] :hidden[name=error]

Comment: I mean how to put instead of A javascript variable ?

Comment: it worked thanks. That's all I need.  By the way please tell me 1 thing.  What's better?   create html form with pictures , buttons etc. and send from server to client via ajax, or send only data and create form with jquery on client side ?

Comment: It depends if you he few elements then you can send html from server but if you have many elements sending data would be faster transfer. Sending data is better option most of time.

Answer (score 0):

After you have done this:

```
$('#'+pic_type+'_n_'+pic_number).html(responseimage);
```

and you are looking for val of `#b` inside form with class `a`, it would be as:

```
$('#'+pic_type+'_n_'+pic_number+ ' form.a #b').val()
```